# Custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to replace standard scrollbar (only appearance) with some custom one (the one from http://scripterlative.com/files/autodivscroll.htm to look like the top-left example from http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php?demo=vert) so the script will still work and scrollbar behave like it wasn't modified?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, custom scrollbars annoy the user and make the page loading time longer. I would leave the UI the way it is.

Comment: you can use jscrollpane right..

Comment: @Evan: Agreed. [Go find the scroll bar](http://www.hoogt.nl/) (reminds me of [this long-standing bug/feature request (?)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18303) in Google Chrome).

Comment: Hi guys, coming back on that question, has anyone tried it with brand new ios6? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510013/css-custom-scrollbars-for-safari-dont-display-on-ios-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webkit [supports](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) it so it is possible in Safari and in Chrome. I tried it once, it works well.

My only problem: Doesn't support showing the scrollbar at the left or the top of the container.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use CSS3 to adapt a custom scrollbar design, to achieve a standard, but different looking scrollbar.

See here [CSS3 CUSTOM SCROLLBARS](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Hope this helps!