# CSS styled scrollbars support for safari mobile on iOS 6 disappeared?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, ios6

I'm having a problem, probably because of Apple and I can't find information about it.

Yesterday I skinned a website's scrollbars with webkit css properties (-webkit-scrollbar, -webkit-scrollbar-track, -webkit-scrollbar-thumb) so it displays nicely on iPads.
Everything was fine looking and scrolling with native behaviour.

Suddenly this morning, after updating my iPad to iOS6, my custom scrollbars disappeared.

This is a big bummer for me and of course there is no information about this on Apple's developper website.

Anyone has experienced the same problem? Can you confirm the problem?

Are some new specs coming or did Apple just stop supporting this???

Comment: It is an interesting thing to be able to style srollbars, but it is never recommended. Many think are not part of the UI you build, so do I. Probably this is why Mozilla hasn't implemented anything like this yet and they do not seam to plan that.

Comment: Well I use jScrollpane on the desktop version of the concerned website and the css webkit scrollbars were the perfect solution to reproduce my UI on iPad while keeping the webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; behaviour...

Comment: Just an idea that most likely won't work. But try dropping the `-webkit` prefixes from the properties to see if that works.

Comment: Yeah I tried that with a slight hope but no dice ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unreleased (AFAIK) reason, Apple removed some of the webkit prefixed CSS properties. This includes the -webkit-scrollbar group.

Comment: Then how do you know? Can you cite your source please?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/standardcssproperties.html Many other prefixed properties remain, but -webkit-scrollbar has been removed.