# Scrollbar customizing

Tags: html, css

I am somewhat new to coding and I am making a profile to practice my HTML and CSS coding. Currently I have this for the profile: [Profile](http://pastebin.com/Ap7wu8bB)
I want to customize the scroll bar to look like this: [Scrollbar](http://pastebin.com/rinXHcR0)
What do I use to customize the scroll bar? Currently the overflow-y is set to auto, do I need to use inhert or something? I want to set this Scrollbar as it's own element so I do not need to totally overhaul the coding I have, thank you.

Comment: Please use http://codepen.io/ to share your code.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve from your question. But if you are looking for customizing scroll bars within a page you can get some guide from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329609/custom-scrollbar